# VPN start freezes Nemo

Tags: vpn, freeze, linux-mint, nemo

I'm on Linux Mint 18.

Every single time I start a VPN connection, be it manually or via autostart or script (I've tried any possibility) the file manager Nemo freezes, i.e. doesn't start up, or, if it was allready started up before starting the VPN, it doesn't react on directory change anymore. I can't even close it.

The VPN itself works fine, though, and it's configured ok. I can play radio stations and download files and use browsers. Only Nemo sucks. (And somehow related apps as Cairo-Dock which try to show directories freeze unisono).

Nemo only responds, mostly, after a while, when I shut down the VPN. Sometimes it even doesn't and I've to reboot the PC. Logout/in only mostly doesn't work.

Does anybody else has this issue and/or does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm mounting a directory from my distant media server per sshfs and fstab so that it's ready to use when I log in.

I found out by trial and error that this mount caused the issue.

My workaround so far is: Unmount the drive, start VPN, remount the drive, and erverything's fine. I can do that with a tiny script.

But I don't understand yet why a mounted drive can freeze my filemanager when I start a VPN.